# mongodb aggregate or loop

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a question about the "aggregate" function of mongodb

if I have a task, I can solve it by loop all documents for just 1 time. But I need to use "aggregate" function (also need to query across all documents) 3 times or more to solve it.

data structure:

```
{
  _id: 'XXX', 
  list_of_content: [{type: 'cat or dog', 'emotion': 'happy or sad'}]
}
```

if my data like this, and I want to count the number of "content" belong to "cat", "dog", "happy" and "sad". if I loop thru the documents, I just need to count the number and solve this issue within just one loop.

if I use aggregate, I will need to unwind it and use 2 aggregate functions

which way is more efficient?

Comment: Its based on your load of data. Basically we use aggregation than looping

Comment: {'_id': 'XXX', list_of_content: [{type: 'cat or dog', 'emotion': 'happy or sad'}]}

if my data like this, and I want to count the number of "content" belong to "cat", "dog", "happy" and "sad".

if I loop thru the documents, I just need to count the number and solve this issue within just one loop. 

if I use aggregate, I need to use 2 aggregate functions...

Comment: How long your data?

Comment: very large..and still growing, currently is about 20k

Comment: since its growing, better you go with aggregation as all the process happens as a single process in database

Comment: thank you~ I saw your comment in my "inbox", but it doesn't display here

Comment: can you check it again

Comment: It's ok now >.<.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation with $group, $sum, and $cond can get what you're looking for.

First unwind the array, then $group by a constant so all of the documents are gathered into a single result, use $sum to count, with $cond to determine which of the sums to increment for each document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$list_of_content"},
  {$group: {
      _id: "counts",
      cats: {
        $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["cat", "$list_of_content.type"]},1,0]}
      },
      dogs: {
        $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["dog", "$list_of_content.type"]},1,0]}
      },
      happy: {
        $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["happy", "$list_of_content.emotion"]},1,0]}
      },
      sad: {
        $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["sad", "$list_of_content.emotion"]},1,0]}
      }   
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SqeS7wPVo0y)